# If a battery was overused will the voltage decrease?

Tags: voltage, batteries

I have a 1.5V battery. When my battery is overused will its voltage remain the same or will it decrease?

Comment: The voltage of almost all batteries fall as they are discharged. Can you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve? Do you have a specific battery type in mind? (You said 1.5V BUT that does not fully explain your actial need)

Comment: Do you have any numbers on what you mean by "overused"?

Answer (score 3):

It will decrease.

A 1.5V alkaline battery will start around 1.6V, and fall as the stored energy is used.  It will fall faster near the end.

So you can use voltage meter as a means to estimate the remaining energy.

If your meter is not very precise, it might be hard to notice the change, and the temperature may change the result slightly.

For more details, look up "discharge curve" for the battery, if the maker publishes that data.

Also see [What's a good estimate on how low an alkaline battery voltage can be to still make the battery useful?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48847/whats-a-good-estimate-on-how-low-an-alkaline-battery-voltage-can-be-to-still-ma?rq=1)